# It is possible to sync android phone scan QR code to a web system?

Tags: android, asp.net, qr-code

I have a asp.net mvc 3 project that can send an email to a user contains the detail through QR Code. Now it is possible to scan that QR Code using android mobile phone then my project will search/register his data in my web system?. I tried searching it but got nothing. If it is possible what is the method or how to solve this problem?.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question but I'm assuming the QR code contains some unique identifier, and you are trying to check if the QR code was scanned. You can't achieve this from a standalone QR code scanner. The mobile device needs to communicate that code back to your server. One way to do that would be to build an Android app that the mobile user can use to scan the QR code and it automatically sends the code value back to your server.

Comment: Sorry if you didn't understand well. I will give an example scenario about this. For example a employee assigned for the registration will scan the printed QR Code of the user/employee after it scan the system will search, search & register him.

Comment: Ok now I understand a bit better. The solution approach would still be as I indicated above. If you want to use an android device to scan the QR code and communicate back with your web system, then you need to develop an app which can scan QR codes and then communicate with your server. I'm doing a similar project now using REST APIs to communicate with the server.

Comment: so api is one of the solution?

Comment: Yes that would be the way for the mobile device to communicate with the server

Comment: @Wind- Sorry for the late response. For example I have an API where/how to use it?.

Comment: You'll need a mobile app, which issues a Request via the API, and a web app, which consumes the API message, does the necessary processing (e.g., update the database), and returns a Response via the API to the mobile app. As for how to use the API, it's best that you post a separate question with your code.